# Interpretation of density wave observables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-interpretations

Given some Hamiltonian quantum system, one can ask questions about (expectation values of) observables. While some have an intuitive meaning, e.g. energy or magnetisation, I find it hard to grasp the idea of objects like **spin/energy/charge density waves**
$$O_k\propto \sum_j \cos(kj)q_j\quad,$$
with momentum $k$ and where $q_j$ is some conserved quantity like spin/energy/charge.

Does anyone have a nice interpretation of such quantities and maybe insight on why such quantities are of interest to physics?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: For example, in a 1d system with lattice constant $a$ and considering $k=\pi/a$,  O is just the quantity in the even site minus the one in the odd sites.